# Power input connector for power distribution board

Tags: power, connector, power-dissipation

I have been looking at several different power distribution module designs and the all seems to use a large bolt for the main power input. I am curious what these connectors are called and how they connect to the PCB internally?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Screw terminals. Often combined with 4mm "banana plug" sockets (but apparently not here)

Comment: It's an earth bonding stud and not a power connector.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have installed this specific system and I am certain that this is the primary power input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for 'feed-through bolt terminal post'.

[image]

Comment: I think this is it. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know that sort of connection as a "terminal post".  Many are designed to accept 4mm banana plugs, but not those.  Many have a hole though the screw thread to push a wire through as well.

The threaded rod normally continues through the insulated base, so a ring terminal and locking nut can be used to make connection to the other end.  My guess is that it would be connected to the circuit board by a short lead.

Comment: I'm still struggling to find these on digikey with "terminal post as the search"

Comment: @user8908459 - I'm in the UK, like *Simon* who wrote the answer, and "terminal post" is what I would call it too. Here are a few links to similar parts, called terminal posts by RS [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/terminal-posts/6457929/) and by Farnell [here](https://uk.farnell.com/pro-signal/psg03033/terminal-post-red/dp/3384011). However on Digikey, they seem to be called "binding posts", see [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/banana-and-tip-connectors-binding-posts/310) for that category on Digikey.com, and you can find similar components. Hope that helps.